# How to count instances of numbers in an array using recursion?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I try to write a function (called: tally) using recursion (part of the exercise) to scan through an array of numbers and return an object with the numbers as key and the number of instances as value.

Example:

```
tally([2,3,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,7,,6,7,6,7,5,4,3,4,5,5,6])
//{2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 3, 5: 10, 6: 4, 7: 3}
```

I created the framework but i am not sure about the syntax to make it work:

```
function tally(arr) {
    var obj = {}
    if (/*check if object ('obj') has a key corresponding to the array element*/) {
        //increase key's value by onee
    } else {
        //add key with value of 1
    }
    return obj
};
```

Any hints to complete the recursion function above? Please try to stick to my structure in your answers as much as possible since this is part of an exercise.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense at all to use recursion here, it only makes things (much) more confusing than they need to be. Do you have to create a new `obj` on each call, and can the `tally` function only accept that one `arr` argument, or can those be changed?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I know - it's for the sake of practice.

Comment: To make it recursive you need to track the counts, the ever-shortening array of remaining values, and a check to know when you're done.

Comment: If you want to use recursion, you need to decide what to recurse over and what the base case will be. That'll be the framework for your recursive function. Then fill in the base case and the recursion step with logic.

Comment: @DaveNewton I'd say the number of counts should be arr.length, right?

Comment: @Bergi this I don't get

Comment: @Stephan-thecurious As suggested by Dave, you will probably want to recurse over the array. Have you seen an example of an array recursion in your course yet?

Comment: @Bergi, yeah I did

Comment: @Stephan-thecurious Can you show us how those looked? They have a particular structure that you will need to replicate in `tally`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are:

```
function tally(arr) {
    if (arr.length == 0) {
        return {}
    }
    var value = arr.pop()
    var obj = tally(arr)
    if (value in obj) {
        obj[value] += 1
    } else {
        obj[value] = 1
    }
    return obj
};
```

EDIT:
It can also be done using `slice()` instead of `pop()`:

```
function tally(arr) {
    if (arr.length == 0) {
        return {}
    }
    var value = arr[0]
    var obj = tally(arr.slice(1))
    if (value in obj) {
        obj[value] += 1
    } else {
        obj[value] = 1
    }
    return obj
};
```

Comment: hmmm ... I haven't covered "pop" yet, so this shouldn't be part of my code (even if it might be right or best practice)

Comment: @Stephan-thecurious Do you know about `slice()`? If not, then you would have to recurse over arrays indices, which is weird.

Comment: Yeah, slice is covered

Comment: As a hint for the exercise I have "The || operator can be handy here..."

Comment: @Stephan-thecurious I've updated the answer with the `slice()` approach

Answer (score 1):

Using extra parameter for an index, `i`, the result, `r` -

```js
const plus1 = (k = "", r = {}) =>
  ( k in r
      ? r[k] += 1
      : r[k] = 1
  , r
  )

const tally = (a = [], i = 0, r = {}) =>
  i >= a.length
    ? r
    : tally
        ( a
        , i + 1
        , plus1(a[i], r)
        )

console.log(tally([2,3,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,7,,6,7,6,7,5,4,3,4,5,5,6]))
```

Output

```
{
  "2": 1,
  "3": 2,
  "4": 3,
  "5": 10,
  "6": 4,
  "7": 3,
  "undefined": 1
}
```

Comment: Do you choose the index parameter over a `slice`-based version chiefly for performance?  Or do you see this simpler than a version that uses a recursive call such as `tally(xs.slice(1), ...)`?

Comment: The majority of my answers exist as a way of seeing the problem solved in another way because this is an effective learning tool for myself. I was going to use destructing assignment but the original question has a sparse input. I then thought about writing a long-format answer to address the issue but then landed on this one instead. The added parameter and `[...]` notation is noisy, but it does offer good performance. Other answers show use of `.slice` so I figured the OP would be made familiar with that technique. I hope all readers can learn something from each answer provided ^^

Comment: Performance that’s immediately thrown away by copying `r` for every item. This is quadratic (in the worst case – specifically Ө(mn) on m = number of distinct elements and n = number of elements).

Comment: Ry thank you for keeping me honest. I think my edit fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

ok, so you are asked to do a recursion just for the sake of it.

This could be done (albeit is hacky) passing an extra parameter to `tally`. When you declare a function in vanilla js you can actually feed it extra stuff. So, in each recursion, pass `obj` as a second parameter:

**EDIT**
Thanks @Bergi, you're right. I'll edit the code

```js
function tally(arr) {
    let obj = arguments.length>1? arguments[1] : {};
    if(arr.length===0) {
      return obj;
    }
    let next_number=arr.pop();
    obj[next_number]=obj[next_number]||0;
    obj[next_number]++;
    
    return tally(arr,obj);
};

let inputArr = [2,3,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,7,6,7,6,7,5,4,3,4,5,5,6],
outputObj=tally(inputArr);
console.log(outputObj);
console.log({outputEmpty:tally([])});
```

Comment: It depends on what you consider "homework". Every one of us that codes for a living does sooner or later rely on StackOverflow, so completing a homework through SO is actually preparing him for the actual job experience

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to guide you to an answer without giving it away entirely, but this is what I would recommend. (There are some problems such as you destroy arr in the process that you may want to consider)

```
function tally(arr, obj) {

    // if the length is zero we've gone through every value
    if(arr.length === 0)
        return obj

    // create obj if we didn't provide it
    if(obj === undefined)
        obj = {}

    // pull the last value from arr
    let val = arr.pop()

    if (/*check if object ('obj') has a key corresponding to the array element*/) {
        //increase key's value by onee
    } else {
        //add key with value of 1
    }

    // move onto the next value
    return tally(arr,obj)

}
```

EDIT: took @Bergi's input

Comment: Better check for `arr.length` than whether the `val` is undefined.